# redirect tail output to a remote serever

Tags: linux, remote, aix, tail

I want to `tail -f` a local file, for example app1.log, and send its output to a file on a remote server.

```
tail -f app1.log >> <remote server>:/home/remote.log
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe `STDOUT` through SSH to a remote host:

`tail -f - app1.log | ssh user@remote.host "cat > app1.log"`

If you don't care too much about encryption end to end, you can spin up `netcat` on the receiving host and pipe `tail` to the remote listening netcat or [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), but that would be evil, so I won't provide copy-pasta. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsyslog if you have rsyslog server on the other side. The problem is, it is very difficult to track what was your last message sent. It all depends on the way you implement it how important your logs are.